# How to block fake IP adresses?

Tags: denial-of-service, spoofing, fail2ban

on my webserver I find in the apache-logfiles:

```
[Wed Jan 09 16:29:10.660069 2019] [:error] [pid 11705] [client 66.249.66.66:39066] script '/var/www/fairtragen/7327991037366506690.php' not found or unable to stat
[Wed Jan 09 16:31:33.649479 2019] [:error] [pid 11793] [client 66.249.66.64:61571] script '/var/www/fairtragen/8760165737201568839.php' not found or unable to stat
```

I have tried to block these requests (to none-existing php-files) with fail2ban. But the IP-Adresses are from some google bot.
I think, someone is trying to prepare a DDOS-Reflection attack against google. Can I block these requests without blocking the real google-bot?

Comment: “trying to prepare a DDOS-Reflection attack against google.” - Sorry, but what? Please elaborate. Google Bot may access not-existing pages when referred there from elsewhere, but that’s generally harmless.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I get these requests very frequently (about every 20sec) and since many days now. I did never have any php-files with similar names.
What other use could anyone have to scan my server with a spoofed IP?

Comment: You cannot really spoof IP addresses on the Internet. If you do, you can’t get a response. This is really Google.

Comment: For a DDos Reflection attack you do not need a response. The response would be sent to google and if it comes from too many Servers they will have a problem.

Comment: The gist of Daniel's comment is still true: someone spoofing their IP address could not get _the initial TCP SYN-ACK response_; without that, they could not establish the TCP connection; and without that, they would be unable to submit this HTTP request at all.